# Get value from read only input with c# web browser

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

I have web browser control c# Win Forms. I cannot get value from read only input element it returns null ""

Please advice me something how i can get text inside this read only element

it returns in innerHml this :

```
"<LABEL>დასახელება ან სახელი, გვარი</LABEL> <INPUT id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtBuyerName class=inactive_input title=\"მაქსიმალური სიმბოლოების რაოდენობა 90\" name=ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtBuyerName readOnly value=\"ცოტნე მემანიშვილი\"> "
```

i want to get this `"ცოტნე მემანიშვილი"`

Thanks

Comment: show us what you tried already.

Comment: I was tried this: var _ServerCompanyNumber = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtBuyerName");
            txtCompanyName.Text = _ServerCompanyNumber.InnerText;

Comment: @Acid: That's two lines of code.  Which one is failing?  Is `_ServerCompanyNumber` what you expect it to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this for a text input:

```
txtCompanyName.Text = txtBuyerName.Text;
```

or this for a hidden input:

```
txtCompanyName.Text = txtBuyerName.Value;
```

Comment: Its does not have .Text option

Comment: You should use naming standarts, as txt refers to a textbox. I edited my answer.

Comment: @FrancisP: I think you're misunderstanding the context of the question.  There is no `txtBuyerName` as a `TextBox`.  He's using a web browser control on a thick client app to access a web page.  The fact that the web page uses ASP.NET on the server-side is immaterial to his client-side usage of the rendered markup.

Comment: @Acid: Sorry, I haven't done much from that angle.  I'm usually writing the server-side stuff.  I imagine I could tinker with the code, but I can't really give a concrete answer.  (Accepting also the possibility that the problem lies _outside_ of the context you've given, such as if the value is being populated with JavaScript and the `WebBrowser` control isn't executing that, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, using `GetElementsByTagName` that returns `HtmlElementCollection` ,then take first child like this:

```
HtmlElementCollection elmnt = browser.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtBuyerName").GetElementsByTagName("value");

txtCompanyName.Text = elmnt[0].InnerText;
```